# SemanticUI Dropdown extension not being found in ElectronJs?

Tags: javascript, electron, semantic-ui

I am trying to use SemanticUI's dropdown with Electron, but for some reason the Javascript component of the dropdown is not being called/found. I have tried using bower, the gulp build, and npm. Nothing has worked so far. This is the code I am using.

**HTML**

```
<head>
  <title>
    ...
  </title>

  <script>
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')
  </script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.3.1/dist/semantic.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.3.1/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

  <script src="../bower_components/semantic-ui-dropdown/dropdown.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/semantic-ui-dropdown/dropdown.min.css" />
  <script src="view.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ui one column stackable center aligned page grid">
    <div class="column twelve wide">
      <h3 class="ui top attached header" id="dInfo">Title</h3>
      <div class="ui attached segment">
        <select class="ui search selection dropdown" id="search-select">
          <option value="">State</option>
          <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
          ...
        </select>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<!--<script src="view.js"></script> (This also fails)-->
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const $ = require('jquery');
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

$(document).ready(() => {

  $('#search-select').dropdown();
})
```

The error ends up being

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropdown is not a function

Any thoughts on why this plugin isn't end being ran?

**Edit:**

If I do not include dropdown.js and dropdown.cs from the semantic-ui-dropdown, there are no errors but this is what the dropdown ends up looking like.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where is your JS code located relative to your scripts in the head tag, `view.js`?

Comment: For some stupid reason I accidently called my Js CSS while asking the question, my bad

Comment: @y0hami the script is in the same folder

Comment: the same folder or file?

Comment: @y0hami Same Folder

Comment: what is the file called, is it the `view.js` file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168795/discussion-between-y0hami-and-jack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up fixing the issue with

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.3.1/dist/semantic.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

  <script>
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.1/semantic.min.js"></script>
  <script src="view.js"></script>
```